# Ubuntu is always crashing

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, lenovo, nvidia-optimus

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 alongside with Windows 8.1 but it's always hanging and I can't finish any work. :(. These are the typical things I'm doing with my Ubuntu.

- Coding using PHPStorm
- Debugging using Google Chrome
- Running Homestead Vagrant
- Using Terminal
- Using Gulp Watcher
- Guake
- Skype

My Laptop is [Lenovo Z500](http://shop.lenovo.com/gb/en/laptops/lenovo/z-series/z500/#tab-tech_specs).

I entered this command `$ free -m`and these are the results

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3808       2697       1111        797         36       1291
-/+ buffers/cache:       1369       2439
Swap:            0          0          0
```

Command `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'`

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3904
    Kernel driver in use: i915
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [GeForce GT 635M] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3904
    Kernel driver in use: nouveau
```

I think my computer's specs are good enough to run these things.
My Ubuntu is updated.

Please help!

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATES**

I monitored my Resources using System monitor and my **Memory and Swap History** is at **80+%** when the following are opened:

- Google Chrome
- PHPStorm
- Vagrant (Running Homestead)
- Gulp (Wacthing)

I haven't open my Skype yet and it's already hanging.

**UPDATES**

I added 4GB of Swap using this tutorial [How To Add Swap](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-14-04)
Now I can open my Skype and it really helps, although sometimes it's still hanging for a few moments then it was okay again.
My Memory is when everythings are open is 82.8% and Swap is only 16.7%.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install  a proprietary graphics driver for Nvidia.

Run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-331 nvidia-prime
```

and reboot.

You will be able to switch Intel and Nvidia adapters in "Nvidia Settings" program. It looks like Intel is enough for your activities.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! installing now. I hope it will fix my issue!

Comment: After reboot, do I need to do something else or default settings are enough?

Comment: Just start Nvidia utility and set the adapter to Intel, if it is not done. Then log off and on. Probably it is on default.

Comment: Ok, I have the NVIDIA X Server Settings. Question do I need to open this everytime I open my laptop?

Comment: No. Just set it once.

Comment: I'm still experiencing my problem. :(.  Also I set my GPU to intel.

Answer (score 1):

You can also upgrade linux kernel

Run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-vivid
```

and reboot.